# Fleet WayPoint : set range of access hours by waypoint

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to set a range of opening access hours for the calculation with findpickups.json?

in the **Nokia HERE** documentation it is indicated that to establish a range of access hours it must be indicated with this method. "acc: mo10: 30: 00 + 01: 00 | mo12: 00: 00 + 01: 00; st: 600", **but is it possible to indicate the following case?**

> From Monday to Friday from 10:30 a.m. to 12 p.m. and from 4:00 p.m. to 8:00 p.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for specifying access hours is as xsd type xs:datetime only

**DDhh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]|DDhh:mm:ss[Z|(+|-)hh:mm]**

For access hours days (DD) are abbreviated with two lowercase characters: mofor Monday, tu for Tuesdainy, we, th, fr, sa, su. Hours (hh) must integer values in the range 0..23. Minutes and seconds must be from the range 0..59.
The first time stamp defines the beginning of the access hours, the second time stamp defines the end of the access hours. The access hours constraints require a service time, which is the length time (to be spent) at the waypoint,

for example acc:mo09:30:00-01:00|12:00:00-01:00;st:600

Specifying the multiple days for one destination is not possible, though you can specify multiple destinations with individual access hours like below illustration

https://wse.api.here.com/2/findpickups.json?departure=2015-05-04T8:00:00%2b01:00&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&app_id={YOUR_APP_ID}&app_code={YOUR_APP_CODE}&start=DuisburgRuhrort;51.4541,6.7406&destination1=ZecheZollverein;51.486,7.0459;acc:mo09:00:00%2b01:00%7cmo10:00:00%2b01:00;st:60&destination2=KokereiZollverein;51.4879,7.0337;acc:mo10:30:00%2b01:00%7cmo12:00:00%2b01:00;st:600&destination3=MuehlheimRuhrHbf;51.432,6.886;acc:mo08:00:00%2b01:00%7cmo09:00:00%2b01:00;st:60&end=DuisburgHafen;51.4576,6.7717&improveFor=TIME